# geopandas find row of POINTS by given coordinate

Tags: geopandas

I have a geopandas file and I am looking for an efficient way to identify the POINT by a given coordinate. For example, I have a geopandas variable like

```
gpd1 = gpd.read_file('file_path')
```

If I have a specific `point` (20, 30), how can I locate the row of `gpd1` whose location is closest or identical to the given point? I am thinking something like

```
select_point = gpd1[gpd1.geometry.x==point[0] & gpd1.geometry.y==point[1]]
```

But I am feeling this method is not very efficient for a large dataset. And this method may not work if the given point is slightly off the point in `gpd1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script finds the nearest geometry (geometries if several on same distance)  for a search point in an efficient way:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import Point

file_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[Point(10, 10), Point(10, 0), Point(-15, 0)])
search_point = Point(0, 1)

search_point_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[search_point], crs=file_gdf.crs)
nearest_in_file_gdf = search_point_gdf.sjoin_nearest(
    file_gdf[["geometry"]], distance_col="distance", rsuffix="nearest"
).set_index("index_nearest")
nearest_in_file_gdf = nearest_in_file_gdf.join(file_gdf, rsuffix="_nearest")
print(nearest_in_file_gdf)
```

Result:

```
                            geometry   distance          geometry_nearest
index_nearest
1              POINT (0.00000 1.00000)  10.049876  POINT (10.00000 0.00000)
```